# I can't stop sprinting in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I press the 'W' button, I sprint automatically. Same thing for when I crouch and press 'W', I still sprint. This is happening on all servers, including singleplayer. It started early this morning (around 5 or 6 am est). I tried changing the keybind, but that's didn't work.

I'm playing Minecraft 1.15.2

Comment: Which Minecraft version?

Comment: Do you still sprint after getting your hunger bars down? If so, do you go back to perma-sprint when you refill the hunger bar again?

Answer (score 3):

@sf kind of already answered this, but here in a bit longer:

This most likely happens, because you have set Sprint to "Toggle" in Options->Accessiibility Settings.
[image: Sprint: Toggle]

In this mode Minecraft remembers if you activated (or deactivated) the sprint mode, even across servers/worlds. If you want to play with that setting, pressing your sprint key (usually Ctrl) switches you between sprinting and not sprinting. Otherwise just change the setting back.